# Load an SWF file and close it in the same window

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm building an app where the user clicks on a button and loads an SWF file in the same window, then if he finishes, closes it with a closing button:

[image: First frame]

[image: 2nd frame]

i want the user to be able to click on the orange closing button, and return to the first frame (the blue one),

i tried this:

```
orangeClosingButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
 function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
  fscommand("quit");
 }
```

but this closes the whole App, i just want to close the gray SWF file, and return to the main App the blue one, any idea how can i achieve this?

Comment: You need to call **Loader.unloadAndStop()** method on the **Loader** instance that holds the loaded SWF: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#unloadAndStop()**

Comment: do i need to call it in the main file (the blue one) or in the loaded file (the gray one) , because the "orangeClosingButton" is in the loaded file.

Comment: Ok, I will post an answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to completely stop and unload a loaded SWF, you need to invoke **unloadAndStop()** method on the **Loader** instance, that holds the loaded content. Like:

```
var outerSwf:Loader = new Loader;

// Load.
outerSwf.load(new URLRequest("outer.swf"));
addChild(outerSwf);

// ...
// Unload.
removeChild(outerSwf);
outerSwf.unloadAndStop();
```

Then, if you want to do it from inside of the loaded content. You can subscribe this method to button click of just call it.

```
function unloadThisSWF(e:Event = null):void
{
    // Obtain the reference to the Loader instance.
    // In AS3 root will always point to the compiled SWF
    // root, not to the topmost root attached to the Stage.
    var aLoader:Loader = root.parent as Loader;

    // Run it only if this SWF was actually loaded.
    if (aLoader)
    {
        // Detach it from display list if attached.
        if (aLoader.parent)
        {
            aLoader.parent.removeChild(aLoader);
        }

        // Invoke the unload.
        aLoader.unloadAndStop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Depends on how you load the inside SWF. Assuming this is ActionScript2 and this code is inside of the loaded movie (grey one) something like this might work:

```
orangeClosingButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
  // remove the event listener so the loaded movie can be garbage collected
  orangeClosingButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
  unloadMovie(this);
}
```

Not sure if you can unload the movie from the inside swf though, maybe this unloadMovie() has to be in the main SWF as well where you have loaded the movie.

if this is AS3 you should use removeChild(yourMovieClip) instead of unloadMovie

Comment: The **unloadMovie** function is an AS1/2 function, not AS3.

Comment: i tried it but i got this error: "The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller"